# Branching & Merging strategy - Linux kernel

Tags: linux, git, github, linux-kernel

## Background

From Linux GitHub page in the last month, 500+ authors have pushed 1946 commits to all branches, excluding merges.

On `master`, 11,000+ files have changed and there are 549K additions and 308K deletions.

800K loc have been touched in 1 month by 600 devs.

All devs globally distributed and work independently. They are not managed by a single manager.

Linux kernel still works!!!

---

## Workflow

Below are the two workflow that I came across:

TBD :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yVy4.png

Gitflow workflow:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRcIZ.png

---

1. What is the work flow that a Linux kernel developer follow? Based on the workflow, what is the merging strategy? to keep `master` branch code with no conflicts.
2. Before `git push`ing the changes from a local repo(laptop), do you pre-verify the commit with some baseline? to verify [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) or non-VCS conflicts
3. In what cases, does Linux kernel developer tag/label a commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 123 of ProGit tells me that the Linux Kernel uses the "Dictator and Lieutenants Workflow" ([Section Distributed Workflows in ProGit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows))

[image: Dictator and Lieutenants Workflow]

This way the verification of the commits is splitted into different stages and each blob is reviewed multiple times I assume. Since I am no Linux Kernel developer myself, I do not know the guidelines how the commits should be tagged.

Comment: There is a large number of [pages on the process](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/process?h=v5.0-rc3).

Comment: merge conflicts are identified by the linux-next maintainer during the merge window and passed to the original authors/maintainers (aka lieutenants in above). Maintainers present a list of changes tags and the dictator will pull these during the release candidates in the merge window.